# Terraform Helm provider path to kubeconfig file

Tags: terraform

I am using Helm provider for terraform, how ever when i try to get the kubeconfig file path on Windows with the following command :

```
provider "helm" {
      kubernetes {
        config_path = "%USERPROFILE%\.kube\config"
      }
    }
```

I am getting the following error messages:

**Error: Invalid escape sequence.
The symbol "." is not a valid escape sequence selector.**

**Error: Invalid escape sequence.
The symbol "c" is not a valid escape sequence selector.**

What is the appropriate command for getting the kubeconfig file path ?

Comment: You have typos in your string where you are escaping non-special characters with backslashes. Change those to forward slashes since it appears you intended those to be a filesystem path.

Comment: Thanks, i was able to resolve this by using double backslashes "%USERPROFILE%\\.kube\\config" .

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and using forward slashes resolved the issue for me.